# AutoMapper не игнорирует поля

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

У меня есть два класса: `ViewModel` и `Model`. В контроллере пытаюсь замапить из `ViewModel` в `Model`, схема (`Profile`) указана на фото ниже. Дело в том, что `opt.Ignore` не работает по неизвестной мне причине. Приложение написано на ASP.NET Core 2.1.

[image: AutoMapper Profile]

Comment: у меня есть два класса один ViewModel и Model, в контроллере пытаюсь замапити из VIewModel в Model, схема (Profile) указана в фото которую прикрапил, дело в том что opt.Ignore не работает по неизвестнои мне причине, приложение написано на ASP.NET Core 2.1

Comment: Пожалуйста, прикрепляйте код текстом, а не картинкой.